# Population and GDP of the UK nations 1950-today

Tags: uk, historical, population, gdp

I'm looking for the **population** and **GDP** of the UK nations (England, Scotland, Wales and Northern Ireland) from the 1950s to today, ideally at the yearly level. Any tip?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Office for National Statistics website is going to be your friend here.

The current [Population Estimates Dataset](https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/populationandmigration/populationestimates/datasets/populationestimatesforukenglandandwalesscotlandandnorthernireland) includes (under 'Mid-2016 detailed time series') [national and regional population estimates going back to 1838](https://www.ons.gov.uk/file?uri=/peoplepopulationandcommunity/populationandmigration/populationestimates/datasets/populationestimatesforukenglandandwalesscotlandandnorthernireland/mid2016detailedtimeseries/ukandregionalpopulationestimates1838to2016.zip).

For GDP there are several options, so it's probably best to look through the available data by searching the ONS website for '[region GDP](https://www.ons.gov.uk/searchdata?q=region+gdp&sortBy=relevance&filter=time_series&q=region+gdp&size=10)' (note this link restricts the search to times series). One option is the [Historical Regional GDP](https://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/grossvalueaddedgva/adhocs/005458historicalregionalgdp1968to1970and1971to1996) dataset, but that only goes back to 1968.

If you can't find exactly the data you need, you can also [ask ONS to release additional data](https://www.ons.gov.uk/aboutus/whatwedo/statistics/requestingstatistics/makingarequest).